# Find minimum not used value in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
+--------+-------+
| Server | Port  |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | 27001 |
| 2      | 27002 |
| 4      | 27004 |
+--------+-------+
```

How you can see - here was 27003 port - but it was deleted some time ago (just for example).

Is there some way to know the **minimum value that is not used** (higher than 27000 for example) in mysql table?
Or there is no way and I need to make an separate table with all ports and column with "used" or "not used" ?

Situation explanation: I am creating game hosting website, and I can use auto-increment for ports, but I will have a lot of deleted/unused ports after some time, and I want to use all of them before increasing port range.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick search on Google for "[first missing number from sequence mysql](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=first+missing+number+from+sequence+mysql)" gives [this page of common MySQL queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php).

It shows you how to [find the first missing number from a sequence](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#71):

*You have a table tbl(id int) with values (1,2,4,18,19,20,21), and you wish to find the first missing number in its sequence of id values:*

```
SELECT t1.id+1 AS Missing 
FROM tbl AS t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.id+1 = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL 
ORDER BY t1.id LIMIT 1; 

+---------+ 
| Missing | 
+---------+ 
|       3 | 
+---------+
```

Comment: Last string must be: "ORDER BY t1.id LIMIT 1;", but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this was answered in 2011 - as of MySQL 5.7 this seems to be more readable and (as per explain on a table of 15M rows) faster than the left join solution:

```
select min(id+1) from tbl
where id+1 not in (select id from tbl)
```

Beware as the above will give you max(id)+1 as well, but you can exclude it at virtually no extra cost:

```
select min(id+1) from tbl
where id+1 not in (select id from tbl)
and id < (select max(id) from tbl)
```