# How to generate Sequential User Code using MySQL Trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created a MySQL Trigger **BEFORE INSERT** on table name **agent_mst** as below

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_id INT;

    SET max_id=(SELECT MAX(agent_id_pk)+1 FROM `agent_mst`);
    IF (max_id IS NULL) THEN
        SET max_id=1;
    END IF;

    SET NEW.date_added=NOW(),
        NEW.date_updated=NOW(),
        NEW.agent_code = CONCAT('SDA', LPAD(max_id, 4,'0'));

END
```

So what it does is, every time we inset a record, it generates agent_code field value to something like **SDA0001, SDA0002, SDA0003, ...**

Now suppose I delete a record with code **SDA0003** and insert new record, it will definitely generate the agent code as **SDA0004**. As it is taking the **max_id** and increasing it with 1. But here I want to get **SDA0003** again. So that all **agent_codes** can stay in sequence. How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you need to identify the first (smallest) missing id. 
check out in this link, a nice way to do it in a select query:
[Find mininum not used value in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464656/find-mininum-not-used-value-in-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

To know next auto increment id try to run below query and check column "Auto_increment":

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM DBName where name = 'tableName'
```